# $H_{I}^{n}(M)\cong H_{I}^{n}(R)\otimes_R M.$

Tags: commutative-algebra, homological-algebra

Let $R$ be a Noetherian ring and $I$ an ideal of $R$. If $n$ is the cohomological dimension of $I$, then why is the following isomorphism true:
$$H_{I}^{n}(M)\cong H_{I}^{n}(R)\otimes_R M.$$

The cohomological dimension of $I$ is defined to be the supremum of the set of integers $i$ such that $H_{I}^{i}(M)\neq 0$ for some $R$-module $M$.

Comment: This question has an answer on MO: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/135309/h-inm-cong-h-inr-otimes-r-m

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will work with total derived functors, I hope it is OK.

So, let us look at the complex $R\Gamma_I (R)$. Note that because we can compute it using the Čech complex, one always has (over noetherian rings):

$R\Gamma_I(M) \cong R\Gamma_I(R) \otimes_R M$ for any $M$.

Now, let us calculate the $n$th cohomology of both sides:

LHS: $H^n(R\Gamma_I(M)) = H^n_I(M)$ - simply by definition.

RHS: $H^n(R\Gamma_I(R) \otimes_R M) = H^{(n+0)}(R\Gamma_I R \otimes_R M) \cong H^n(R\Gamma_I R) \otimes_R H^0(M)$ $=$ $H^n_I(R) \otimes_R M$. This follows from the Künneth spectral sequence since for $i>n$ we have $H^i_I(R) = 0$, and for $j>0$ we have $H^j(M)=0$, because we consider $M$ as a complex concentrated in degree $0$.

Comparing both, we get the required isomorphism:

$H^n_I(M) \cong H^n_I(R) \otimes_R M$.

Comment: Can you elaborate more on $R\Gamma_I(M) \cong R\Gamma_I(R) \otimes_R M$ for any $M$.

Comment: If $R$ is noetherian, $a_1,\dots,a_n$ is a sequence that generates $I$, and $C(a_1,\dots,a_n)$ is the Cech complex associated to this sequence, then there is a functorial isomorphism in the derived category $R\Gamma_I(M) \cong M\otimes C(a_1,\dots,a_n)$. Thus what you asked in the comment follows from associtiviaty of the tensor product.

Comment: In general you can read for example in Weibel's homological algebra. But for now - by total derived functor I just mean that you skip the last step in constructing derived functors, that is - don't take cohomology

Comment: I still have one question: How do we see that the spectral sequence $E_{p,q}^{2}=Tor_{p}(H_q(C(a,R)),M)$ collapses? Once this does, then we get the solution. It is clear that it is zero for $q$ greater than $n$, but that itself is not enough.

Comment: Note that $C(a,R)$ is a complex of flat modules.

Comment: yes i did note that, one cannot even apply kunneth spectral sequence without noting that. I think i am missing something. Can  you tell me why the $E_2$ term becomes zero?

Comment: I agree that $C(a,R)$ is flat but $H_q(C(a,r))$ is not, so that is why i cannot see how the spectral sequence collapses. Thanks